# How to find even numbers then add them - JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while

I have coded this

```
int A = 69;
do {
    A /= 2;
    if (A % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(A);
    }
} while (A != 1);
```

Output:

```
34
8
4
2
```

How to sum output? In order to be:

```
34 + 8 + 4 + 2 = 48
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may declare a variable to keep track of the sum:

```
int a = 69;
int sum = 0;

do {
    a /= 2;
    if (a % 2 == 0) {
        String output = (sum > 0) ? " + " : "";
        System.out.print(output + a);
        sum += a;
    }
} while (a > 1);

System.out.print(" = " + sum);
```

This prints:

```
34 + 8 + 4 + 2 = 48
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat The problem here is integer division, which, by default, truncates.  Yes, the OP might want to clarify this point.

Comment: thank you, this worked
it's just that inputting the results to 48

not
34 + 8 + 4 + 2 = 48

but thanks, I can use it as a study.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually I did not read the question properly.

Comment: @FERLYWAHYU I edited my answer so that it now matches the output you are expecting.